# jquery .hide().fadeIn() ie cleartype glitch

Tags: jquery, hide, fadein, cleartype

I have added this in my js:

```
    function customFades() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
            return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie) 
                    this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); 
                if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                    callback(); 
            });
        };

        $.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
            return this.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, speed, function() {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie) 
                    this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); 
                if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                    callback(); 
            });
        };


    })
    (jQuery);
}
```

And now I have a problem when using .hide().fadeIn();

So my question is how can I apply the same type of fix on this issue?

Comment: Do I add something like 
  $.fn.hide = ??
Or should it more like 
  $.fn.hide().fadeIn() = ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems as the problem only occurs when I chain the animations .hide().fadeIn(); If I just use .fadeIn() then it works..